# Calling template function with conditionals

Tags: c++, templates

Given a function with type template :

```
template<typename TYPEA, typename TYPEB, typename TYPEC> 
void foo (TYPEA a, TYPEB b, TYPEC c) { ...; }
```

Then I hope to call this function by the approach shown as follows:

```
int main (void) {
    int ta = 32; 
    int tb = 64;
    int tc = 32;

    float *array_a; 
    double *array_b; 
    float *array_c; 

    foo<(ta == 32 ? float : double), (tb == 32 ? float : double), (tc == 32 ? float : double)>(array_a, array_b, array_c); 

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, this code results in compile error...

However, I just wonder that whether there is a convenient way to check ta's, tb's, and tc's value and call function foo accordingly...

Comment: `ta` and friends have values that could change at runtime. The template parameters must be know at compile time.

Comment: The constness of the t's isn't enough, the conditional operator cannot be used to return types like that.  You'll need some template metaprogramming to be able to choose the types based on `constexpr` quantities if you can make the t's constants.  If they have to stay variable, then you have to pull the conditional checks outside the call to foo and put 8 foo calls in each nested conditional branch.

Comment: This is possible only if ta, tb, and tc are known at compile time (as `constexpr`s), and even then you will need to use complicated template metaprogramming techniques.

Comment: @Wei-Fan Chiang: Your question has little to do with *calling* a function. Your question is about *instantiation* of a template. Template instantiation is a compile-time process. It cannot possibly depend on run-time parameters, regardless of how you slice it. The problem you are trying to solve has nothing to do with templates.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, choosing the type to use to instantiate a template based on the value of a variable and the conditional operator is syntactically wrong. The language doesn't allow the type to be chosen by that method.

Second, you can let the compiler deduce the type. You can just use:

```
foo(array_a, array_b, array_c);
```

The compiler will deduce `TYPEA` to be `float*`, `TYPEB` to be `double*`, and `TYPEC` to be `float*`.

Using

```
foo<float, double, float>(array_a, array_b, array_c);
```

is not correct since the types used to instantiate the template don't match the argument types.

Third, if you want to be able to derive the type based on a value, the value has to be `const` or `constexpr`. You can use:

```
template <int N> struct TYPE_Chooser { using type = double; };
template <> struct TYPE_Chooser<32> { using type = float; };

int main ()
{
    const int ta = 32; 
    const int tb = 64;
    const int tc = 32;

    using typea = typename TYPE_Chooser<ta>::type;
    using typeb = typename TYPE_Chooser<tb>::type;
    using typec = typename TYPE_Chooser<tc>::type;

    foo<typea, typeb, typec>(10, 20, 30); 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Cameron pointed out in the comments, template parameters must be known at compile time.  Moreover, types are not first-class values in C++, so you cannot return them as values from an expression, as you are attempting.

Looking at your code, it appears that you might get what you want by simply passing your arrays to `foo`, as follows:

```
float *array_a; 
double *array_b; 
float *array_c; 

foo(array_a, array_b, array_c);
```

Since the types of `array_a`, `array_b`, and `array_c` *are* known at compile time, and `foo` declares each as a separate type parameter, the compiler will create a function `foo(float*, double*, float*)`, which is the effect you were trying to produce, it seems.